# findK() in c++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

```
// find the largest k for which b[k]<b[k+1]
// ...if one exists


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// find the largest k for which b[k]<b[k+1] if one exists
// returns -1 if such a k doesn't exist
int findK(int b[])
{

}



int main()
{
  int x[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};                  // k=7
  // int x[9] = {5,4,3,2,1,9,7,6,10};                 // k=7
  // int x[9] = {21,22,23,19,18,17,16,3,1};           // k=1
  // int x[9] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};                 // k doesn't exist
  // int x[9] = {8,9,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};                    // k=0, 

  int k;

  k = findK(x);
  cout<<"K="<<k<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is a little program that calls a function to locate the k index for the algorithm. In the lecture we defined this index as "the largest index k such that b[k] < b[k + 1]" if it exists. When it doesn't exist, we've generated all the permutations (well...only if we started with the right initial permutation).

The "if it exists" part means that we have to deal with two possibilities...either it exists or it doesn't. The easiest way to deal with this is to have the function return a good k-value or a value that flags that no such k exists...like -1.

My question is... What is a k index that I am looking for in the first place?

Comment: You function should also take the size of the array so you know when to stop searching. ... and a good indicator of the found object is a pointer/iterator of the object with a pointer/iterator [just] past the last element being a good candidate to indicate that there was no place found.

Comment: One within the bounds of the array given as parameter, so you can loop through [0-8] for your sample (array always contains 9 elements). To make it more general, you'll either need to specify the length of the array as an additional parameter, or even better use a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @g-makulik: given that he is looking for the last case where the ordering condition applies it seems easiest to loop over `b + 8` to `b`: std::adjacent_find(std::rbegin(array), std::rend(array), std::less<int>())` would do the trick...

Comment: @DietmarKühl I just wanted to point out the ranges for `k`, the OP can operate on. You're obviously right with you solution (but may be that's beyond the actual course level the OP's working on ;) ).

Comment: int findK(int b[])
    {
    int k;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
    if (b[i]<b[i+1])
    k=i;
    }
    return k;
    }

Comment: that code seemed to work. Now I just need to add in the return for when it does not exist.

Comment: @g-makulik: Although I don't expect the solution to actually involve reverse iterators or `std::adjacent_find()`, searching from the back to find the last instance of something is actually simpler than searching for the last instance from the front! Going from the front you need to keep searching and remember the last match so far. Searching from behind you are done when you found the first instance. ... and I hope it isn't beyond any course level to replace `++i` or `i += 1` or some such by `--i` or `i -= 1`.

Comment: @user3093082: just initialize `k` with the value you want to return if there is no match and unconditionally return `k`. As said in my previous comment: search from the back to the front and return the moment there is a match! If you fall out of the loop, return the indicator for no match found.